# Created Method is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code first

```
public void StringToInt(int[] arrPart, int temp , string[] arrPartStr)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < arrPart.Length; c++)
    {
        temp = 0;

        if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'P') temp = PLAYER * 100;
        else if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'B') temp = BANKER * 100;
        else temp = TIE * 100;
        if (arrPartStr[c][1] == 'P') temp += PLAYERBANKER;
        if (arrPartStr[c][2] == 'P') temp += BANKERPLAYER;

        arrPart[c] = temp;
    }
}

public static string SplitString(string history)
{
    string[] text = history.Split(',');

    return history;
}
```

Now on here's where I apply all those methods i created

```
public void firstMethod(string history)
{
    string[] arrPartStr = new string[] { SplitString(history) };
    int[] arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];
    int temp = 0;
    StringToInt(arrPart, temp, arrPartStr);
}
```

Now what is happening here is that the code inside the `firstMethod()` is not working properly how did i say so . Because it doesn't get the expected output I want . But the following code

```
public void firstMethod(string history)
{
    string[] arrPartStr = history.Split(',');
    int[] arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];

    for (int c = 0; c < arrPart.Length; c++)
    {
        int temp = 0;

        if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'P') temp = PLAYER * 100;
        else if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'B') temp = BANKER * 100;
        else temp = TIE * 100;
        if (arrPartStr[c][1] == 'P') temp += PLAYERBANKER;
        if (arrPartStr[c][2] == 'P') temp += BANKERPLAYER;

        arrPart[c] = temp;
    }
}
```

Works perfectly when I just put directly the code inside the `firstMethod()` . Could someone enlighten me why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your splitstring function is returning `history` instead of `text`; in other words, you split the string but then return the original string instead of the new, split object. Instead, return text like this:

```
public static string[] SplitString(string history){

    string[] text = history.Split (',');

    return text;
}
```

And then call it like this

```
string[] arrPartStr = SplitString (history);
```

instead of

```
string[] arrPartStr = new string[] {SplitString (history)};
```

Comment: This alone won't work, as you need to change the caller to `string[] arrPartStr = SplitString(history)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if i do that it would give me ` Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `string[]'`

Comment: @TheGinxx009 No, it won't, if you change the declaration of `SplitString` as Nick answered